# how to obtain default Informix Connect/SDK version on Windows?

Tags: windows, informix

I need to detect the exact version of the informix client installed on the machine I interested on the default version that a program not changing the environment will use.

and by exact version I refer to get 3.50.tc4 or 3.50.fc5 instead of only 3.50 and a "none" when there is no Informix installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came was to read from the registry

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Informix\Environment\INFORMIXDIR
```

and look for the files:

```
  $INFORMIXDIR/etc/.lvers_csdk
  $INFORMIXDIR/etc/.lvers_conn
```

that contains the text of the version.(for example: "3.70.FC8")

And with this I can also know if is the CSDK or only the connect install.

Answer (score 2):

You can locate one of Informix Client libraries like `iclit09b.dll`. After installing Informix Client it should be on `PATH`. Then you can read it Version Info.

I have created Python program that uses `win32api` and can search such libraries on `PATH` and then show its attributes: date, size and version info. You can download it from https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576522-searching-dll-and-exe-files-in-path/

For `iclit09b.dll` it prints:

```
2014-06-04 11:10:05  1015808 [b]    C:\informix\bin\iclit09b.dll    ProductVersion 4.10.TC4DE; FileVersion 4.10.TC4DE
```